# how to shorten long URLs in jsp?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I increased the max entry size of URLs from a 100 to 300, but now when displayed, they run over the screen. How can i shorten these URLs to end with three dots if they cant fit on the page.

```
    <c:forEach items="${targets}" var="target">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td class="data">
                <c:if test="${not empty target.valueString}">
                    <a href="<c:out value="${target.valueString}"/>" target="_blank"><c:out value="${target.valueString}"/></a>
                    <spring:message code="entry.confirmDelTarget" var="confirmDelete" />
                    <a href="#" onClick="if(confirm('${confirmDelete}')) document.entryForm.actionBtn.value='delTarget';document.entryForm.targetId.value='${target.id}';document.entryForm.submit();">
                        <img src="/theme/images/gfx/ico_delete2.gif"/>
                    </a>
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: How would they work if you shorten them out with `...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with

```
<c:out value="${target.valueStringTruncated}"/>
```

and

```
public String getValueStringTruncated() {
    if (valueString.length() > 100) {
        return valueString.substring(0, 97) + "...";
    }
}
```

Or you could extract this code to a JSP tag or an EL function:

```
<c:out value="${myFn:truncate(target.valueString)}"/>
```